# DropDown dependency based on 3 tables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get values based on previous dropdownlist value. But I am confused because there are 3 tables that are dependent.

```
dbo.Client
ClientID(PK) | ClientName

dbo.Client_POC_Bridge
ClientID(FK) | POCID (FK)

dbo.PointOfContact
POCID(PK) | FName | LName
```

I have 2 dropdownlist:

DropDownList1: I have binded CLient's table information

```
DropDownList2: I need FName and Lname from dbo.PointOfContact
```

So far, this is the code, but it is not working..

```
protected void DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DropDownList6.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList6.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Point Of Contact--", ""));
            DropDownList6.AppendDataBoundItems = true;

            String var = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KKSTechConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            String strQuery = "select FirstName, POCID from PointOfCContact " +
                               "where ClientID=@ClientID";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(var);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientID",
                DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                DropDownList6.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DropDownList6.DataTextField = "FirstName";
                DropDownList6.DataValueField = "POCID";
                DropDownList6.DataBind();
                if (DropDownList6.Items.Count > 1)
                {
                    DropDownList6.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    DropDownList6.Enabled = false;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581792.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following Line...Use Inner Join to get the Values...

```
String strQuery ="select pof.FirstName, pof.POCID from PointOfCContact pof Inner Join Client_POC_Bridge cpb On pof.POCID =cpb.POCID where cpb.ClientID=@ClientID";
```

Comment: Nice.. But its not searching from dbo.Client.. Should we join even that and then Search for @ClientrID??

Comment: If you want FirstName & POCID to be retreive then there is no need to use dbo.Client,but if you want "ClientName" also then you have to join the dbo.Client to get that...